# Why my php backend don't have data of json post?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

I have got array of json:

```
[Object { path="/usr/share/htvcenter/storage/Windows",  imgid="14698227485587"}, Object { path="/usr/share/htvcenter/storage/WindowsServer",  imgid="14701636866762"}]
```

And I send this array with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: urlstring,
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify(parameters),

          success: function(data){
                $('.lead').hide();
                blackalert('Removed successfully!');
          }
    });
```

I see this in firebug for post send:
[image]

But server answer is with empty $_POST:
[image]

Server's code is:

```
if (isset($_GET['treeaction']) && $_GET['treeaction'] == 'remove') {
        echo 'here';
        var_dump($_POST); die();
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you want to get `$_POST` but in your code it is `$_GET` which is which?

Comment: var_dump($_POST); so main data is in post. In get I am checking action of removing, get goes in url, on which POST sends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a `POST` request you don't need to set the content type to `application/json`. By doing so this is no longer a regular POST request (with form values), but a payload request.

To get the data from a payload request on your server you can use:

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump(json_decode($content)); // In case the content is a json string.
```

If you want to send a regular request, you can use:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      ....
      data: {'data' : parameters},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
});
```

Without the `contentType` and without the `JSON.stringify`.
This way you can get the data with `$_POST['data']`