# jQuery ajax post URL with query string cannot get $_POST in server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

My url parameter need to included the query string due to the system need to pass the token everytime request a link. I would like to use ajax POST to my PHP page.

Below is my ajax code:-

```
var data = new Array();
data[0] = $('#coupon_code').val();
data[1] = $('#coupon_value').val();

var jsondata = {"data": data}
var json = JSON.stringify(jsondata);

$.ajax({
    url:"index.php?route=coupon/create&token=csrf1234567",
    cache:false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data:{json},
    success:function(){}
});
```

However, my PHP script is like below to make sure I have everything passed to server side:

```
public function create()
{
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
}
```

It only have following output:-

```
array(2) {
  ["route"]=>
  string(13) "coupon/create"
  ["token"]=>
  string(11) "csrf1234567"
}
```

Inside the chrome insepct it shows

```
**Query String Paramaters**
route:coupon/create
token:csrf1234567


**Request Payload**
[object Object]
```

It does not have POST variable to pass to my PHP. I want to use type POST, and json to accomplish this, any idea how to solve it?

SOLVED:

```
data:{json},
```

change to

```
data:json,
```

Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Why do you have { around the stringified data and why do you stringify it all let it send and let query stringify. Also it will come through as form data.

Comment: I had tried many method in the json. I put directly into the ajax(): data: {var_coupon_code = $('#coupon_code').val();}, it also turn out [object Object], this is the latest one I had try but still having no POST variable in server side.

Comment: Should `javascript` be `data:json`,  `php` be `var_dump($_POST);` or `print_r($_POST);`? https://jsfiddle.net/wu0kx3nq/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my php backend don't have data of json post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928654/why-my-php-backend-dont-have-data-of-json-post)

Comment: @guest271314 nice catch for the data: {json}, thank you so much!

Comment: @Dekel, I tried the solution, it have to fix my {json} bug, then your solution link will be work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
data:{json},
```

change to

```
data:json,
```

Thanks for guest271314!